# Automatic sorting not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble with auto sorting.
It works great in one of my google scripts but not the other.

The logger shows it should work but it doesn't sort.

> [18-08-01 20:07:48:504 EDT] 3 == 3
>   [18-08-01 20:07:48:506 EDT] FIDO== FIDO

Here is the code:

```
function onEdit(event){
 var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
 var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

 var columnToSortBy = 3;
 var tableRange = "A4:G999";

 if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy && sheet.getName() == "FIDO")
 Logger.log (editedCell.getColumn() + " == " + columnToSortBy);
 Logger.log (sheet.getName() + "== " + "FIDO");
 {   
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, because of the position of those `Logger` statements relative to your conditional statement and the braces, you do not have conditional entry to the code block enclosed by those braces. Instead, you have conditional execution of the statement `Logger.log (editedCell.getColumn() + " == " + columnToSortBy);`. I recommend reviewing the documentation for the `Range#sort` method if you are having trouble sorting on your desired column.